When using ForEach, can you dynamically increment a number for an array element in a view?
I have a ForEach that displays 70 buttons:
import SwiftUI

struct BoxView: View {
    @ObservedObject var gameLogic: GameLogic
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0..<10) { number in
                HStack {
                    ForEach(0..<7) { number in
                        ButtonView(gameLogic: GameLogic())
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Each view includes another view - ButtonView:
import SwiftUI

struct ButtonView: View {
    @ObservedObject var gameLogic: GameLogic
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { gameLogic.displayLetter(whichBox: 0) }) {
            Text(gameLogic.boxLabel[0])
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.title)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .border(gameLogic.boxOutline[0])
        }
        .disabled(gameLogic.letterBoxDisabled[0])
    }
}

There are three arrays and a function within the ButtonView struct. Each instance of the button needs to have a different array element number and pass a different number in the function - from 0 to 69. I'm not sure if this is possible. The only thing I could think to try was to create a variable in gameLogic and increment it by 1 in each iteration of the button. However, I wasn't able to add code to increment that number in the BoxView struct. I get: "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'."
I'm sure there's a way to do this but, being new to Swift and SwiftUI, I don't know what it is. Thanks.

Note, currently you pass a new GameLogic() to your ButtonView every time it is used. These models have nothing to do with each others.
At the very least you should pass the same model such as: ButtonView(gameLogic: gameLogic).
Also you should not use indices eg gameLogic.boxLabel[0] etc... without first checking they exist.
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code .

ForEach already gives you something that increments for each ButtonView - number!
ForEach(0..<7) { number in
                 ^^^^^^

Pass this to ButtonView:
ForEach(0..<7) { number in
    // you should not pass a new "GameLogic()" here. Your probably intended to pass the existing "gameLogic" in BoxView, right?
    ButtonView(index: number, gameLogic: gameLogic)
        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
}

struct ButtonView: View {
    let index: Int
    
    @ObservedObject var gameLogic: GameLogic
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { gameLogic.displayLetter(whichBox: index) }) {
            Text(gameLogic.boxLabel[index])
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.title)
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .border(gameLogic.boxOutline[index])
        }
        .disabled(gameLogic.letterBoxDisabled[index])
    }
}


Side note: instead of parallel arrays, I would create a struct like this:
struct Box: Hashable {
    var outline: Color
    var label: String
    var disabled: Bool
}

Then you can declare an array of Boxes in GameLogic, instead of 3 arrays.
class GameLogic: ObservableObject {
    // instead of these
    /*
    @Published var boxOutline = [Color]()
    @Published var boxLabel = [String]()
    @Published var letterBoxDisabled = [Bool]()
     */
    // write:
    @Published var boxes: [Box] = ...
    
    func displayLetter(whichBox index: Int) { ... }
}

